# A simple pivot but can't get my head around it - please assist..:-)

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I try to do a simple pivot in MS SSMS, but can't figure it out.

This is my data set:

```
Date        CallerANI      Skills               CallerDNIS
2019-05-27  27315391449    loc-SPD-CSR-OverFlow 47515070001
2019-05-27  27315391449    cc-Loc-Voice         Transfer
```

and statement:

```
SELECT [Date],
       CallerANI,
       [47515001101],
       [Transfer]
FROM (SELECT [Date], Skills, CallerANI, CallerDNIS FROM #TempDB) AS p
PIVOT (MAX(Skills)
       FOR CallerDNIS IN ([47515001101], [Transfer])) AS pvt;
```

I want to pivot so that the result looks like this:

```
Date            CallerANI              [47515070001]            [Transfer]
2019-05-27      273135391449           loc-SPD-CSR-OverFlow     cc-loc-Voice
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer to use a Cross Tab over the inbuilt `PIVOT` function. I find it far easier to use:

```
SELECT [Date],
       CallerANI,
       MAX(CASE WHEN V.CallerDNIS = '47515070001' THEN Skills END) AS [47515070001],
       MAX(CASE WHEN V.CallerDNIS = 'Transfer' THEN Skills END) AS [Transfer]
FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(date,'20190527'),27315391449,'loc-SPD-CSR-OverFlow','47515070001'),
             (CONVERT(date,'20190527'),27315391449,'cc-Loc-Voice','Transfer')) V([Date],CallerANI,Skills,CallerDNIS)
GROUP BY [Date],
         CallerANI;
```

Comment: Hi Larnu! Thank you for your prompt reply - much appreciated.  I will analyse your answer and adapt it accordingly (I think it can work).  Problem is I have a table with 10 000+ rows but understand your approach. Thanks once again! Ernie

Comment: Is that 10,000 rows of distinct values you need to pivot @ErnievanWyk ? if so, you'll likely want a dynamic pivot, but having a larger dataset to work with would then make that a lot easier to understand.

Comment: Based on time and callerani combination the values will be distinct. But I came right with your help!  Thanks!  I have the table in the result I want it to be.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome @ErnievanWyk. If it helps, please do mark the answer as the solution so that future readers know that the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The below code helps you to **dynamically** **Pivot** N number of rows

```
DECLARE @DynamicCols VARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #temp ([Date] DATE, [CallerANI] VARCHAR(MAX), [Skills] VARCHAR(MAX), [CallerDNIS] VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #temp 
VALUES ('2019-05-27','27315391449','loc-SPD-CSR-OverFlow','47515070001'),
       ('2019-05-27','27315391449','cc-Loc-Voice','Transfer'),
       ('2019-05-27','27315391449','cc-Loc-Voice-abc','SoMe')

SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT @DynamicCols = STUFF([Cols],1,1,'') FROM (
SELECT [Cols] = (SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([CallerDNIS]) FROM #temp A
                   FOR XML PATH('') ) ) A;

EXEC ('
SELECT [Date], [CallerANI], ' + @DynamicCols+'
FROM #temp
PIVOT 
(
  MAX([Skills])
  FOR [CallerDNIS] in (' + @DynamicCols+')
) PIV');
```